# Create a running average from a list

Tags: python, moving-average

First time Python user and I am lost.  I need to create a table from a list that displays the daily temperature and the running average of temperature up to that day.

```
xData = arange(1,32)    
tData = [86,87,84,86,86,86,84,83,90,89,88,85,86,79,83,81, \
     75,80,81,85,81,88,89,87,84,85,86,88,88,90,90]
avg = [86.]  # First value for monthly avg high temp is just the Day 1 temp
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to start, to make it a running average.  I know how to do a "regular" average, I just don't know how to make it a "running average"

Comment: What version of Python? If you can wait for 3.4, just `import statistics` and it's a one-liner. For 3.1-3.3, you can use [the backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stats/) on PyPI. Otherwise, you have to write a few lines of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A running average is just, for each value in a list, the average of all of the values up to that one. For a stripped-down version of your example:

```
>>> tData = [86,87,84,86]
```

The running averages are `86/1`, `(86+87)/2`, `(86+87+84)/3`, and `(86+87+84+86)/4`.

So, at each index, the running average is the running total, dividing by (index + 1).

You can get the running totals with [`accumulate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
>>> list(accumulate(tData))
[86, 173, 257, 343]
```

And you can get the (1-based) indexes with `enumerate`:

```
>>> list(enumerate(accumulate(tData, start=1))
[(1, 86), (2, 73), (3, 257), (4, 343)]
```

So, just divide:

```
>>> [total / index for index, total in enumerate(accumulate(tData, start=1))]
[86.0, 86.5, 85.66666666666667, 85.75]
```

---

Or using `statistics` in Python 3.4, or its backport/predecessor [`stats`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stats/) for 3.1-3.3:

```
>>> from stats import running_average
>>> running_average(tData)
[86, 86.5, 85.66666666666667, 85.75]
```

---

Of course you can always do it explicitly if you prefer:

```
>>> running_sum, running_sums = 0, []
>>> for value in tData:
...     running_sum += value
...     running_sum.append(running_sum)
>>> [value / index for index, value in enumerate(running_sums, start=1)]
[86, 86.5, 85.66666666666667, 85.75]
```

… or even:

```
>>> running_sum, running_averages = 0, []
>>> for index, value in enumerate(tData, start=1):
...     running_sum += value
...     running_averages.append(running_sum / index)
>>> running_averages
[86, 86.5, 85.66666666666667, 85.75]
```

Comment: +1. `enumerate` accepts a second argument for a starting value.  If you start at 1 then you don't need to add it later.   Very up to date with the `statistics` module. Do you lurk on the python dev mailing list?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Thanks. I don't know how I forgot about the `start` parameter, but I've updated the answer. And I skim both python-dev and python-ideas to keep up, and also occasionally look for new stuff on the PEP list. Even rejected proposals often include interesting ideas…

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this:

```
def runningAvgs(data):
    avg = data[0]
    for i, d in enumerate(data[1:], start=1):
        yield avg
        avg = ((i * avg) + d) / (i + 1.0)
    yield avg

tData = [86,87,84,86,86,86,84,83,90,89,88,85,86,79,83,81, \
     75,80,81,85,81,88,89,87,84,85,86,88,88,90,90]

print list(runningAvgs(tData))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
def cumSeries(series):
    result = [0]
    for s in series:
        result.append(s + result[-1])
    return result

def runningAvg(series):
    cs = cumSeries(series)
    return [(cs[i] - cs[0]) / float(i) for i in range(1, len(cs))]


tData = [86,87,84,86,86,86,84,83,90,89,88,85,86,79,83,81, \
     75,80,81,85,81,88,89,87,84,85,86,88,88,90,90]

print runningAvg(tData)
```

Using cumulative series is a very useful way of working with sums over parts of a series.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) and [operators](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html)

```
from itertools import starmap, accumulate
from operator import add

def moving_average(data):
   moving_sum = enumerate(accumulate(data, add)), start=1)
   return starmap(lambda index, elem: elem / index, moving_sum)
```